# Wireless is not working on my lenovo E4430 having ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Realtek 8723BE802.11n PCI wireless). There is no icon to enable wireless

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, realtek

Initially wireless was working in my lenovo E4430 having Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I updated Ubuntu 12.04 in root, wireless stopped working. Now Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless driver is not activated while earlier it was activated and was in use. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS again and again but no use. I tried but could not find Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless driver for Ubuntu 12.04 on the Internet. Please suggest me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know this problem at another Lenovo. The small radio-card under a cover at the backside was "dead". It was cheaper to use a Wifi-dongle on a USB-port than to buy a new Wifi-card. Ubuntu works fine with it.